# How do I correctly handle this table with multiple embedded form rows in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have this table where I loop through data from the backend. One of the rows contain a form with hidden input fields.

The table displays properly but the input fields are not bound to the form.

This is the SFC for the page:

```
<template>
    <jet-action-section>
        <template #title>
            Pending Bills
        </template>

        <template #description>
            A list of all pending payments.
        </template>

        <template #content>
            <h3 class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-200" v-if="pendingBills.length > 0">
                Pending Payments.
            </h3>

            <div class="mt-3 max-w-xl text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-300" v-if="pendingBills.length > 0">
                <div class="p-6 overflow-x-auto">
                    <table class="w-full whitespace-nowrap">
                        <tr class="text-left font-bold text-white">
                            <th class="bg-blue-500 border-4 p-2 rounded">Payment Description</th>
                            <th class="bg-blue-500 border-4 p-2 rounded">Amount</th>
                            <th class="bg-blue-500 border-4 p-2 rounded">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr v-for="(bill, index) in pendingBills" :key="bill.id" class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200 hover:bg-blue-200 dark:hover:bg-blue-300 focus-within:bg-blue-100">
                            <td class="border-2 p-2">{{ bill.message }}</td>
                            <td class="border-2 p-2">₦{{ bill.amount }}</td>
                            <td class="border-2 p-2" :id="bill.id">
                                <form @submit.prevent="payPerformanceFee(index)">
                                    <input id="amount" type="hidden" v-model="form.amount" />
                                    <input id="goal_id" type="hidden" v-model="form.goal_id" />
                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                                        <jet-button class="ml-4" :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }" :disabled="form.processing">
                                            Pay Performance Fee
                                        </jet-button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h3 class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-200" v-else>
                Payments you're yet to pay will show up here.
            </h3>
        </template>
    </jet-action-section>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import JetActionSection from '@/Jetstream/ActionSection.vue'
import Pagination from '@/Jetstream/Pagination.vue'
import JetButton from '@/Jetstream/Button.vue'
import { useForm , usePage} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'


defineProps({pendingBills: Object})

const bills = computed(() => usePage().props.value.pendingBills)
console.log(bills.value) //this returns all the data from the backend

bills.value.forEach((value, index) => {
    const amount = value.amount
    const goal_id = value.goal_id
    console.log(goal_id) //this gives the expected values
    console.log(amount) //this gives the expected values
})

const form = useForm({
    amount: bills.value.amount, //this show up as undefined in vue dev tools
    goal_id: bills.value.goal_id //this show up as undefined in vue dev tools
    
})

function payPerformanceFee(index) {
    form.post(route('pending.bill'))
}
</script>
```

The page displays like this: [image: Page screenshot]

When I click on the button, it hits the backend with no data.

What I'm trying to achieve is to map amount and goal_id values to the corresponding inertia form so that the data is sent to the backend when the button is clicked. Obviously only one button can be clicked at a time.

I got stuck at the foreach loop. I don't know how to pass each loop cycle data to the inertia form or if I'm going about this the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not using the `<form>` element. This is helpful when you're building forms without a frontend framework, but unless you want a fallback to work without js and using a framework this can get into the way.

Anothe issue I see is that you're using `<input id="amount" type="hidden" v-model="form.amount" />` in a loop. `id`s are meant to be unique, yet your code would generate multiple, so if you're doing a lookup by id, it will return the first one every time.

But, it looks like the id is not even being called. You're using `v-model="form.amount"` and `v-model="form.goal_id"`, where form is:

```js
const form = useForm({
    amount: bills.value.amount, //this show up as undefined in vue dev tools
    goal_id: bills.value.goal_id //this show up as undefined in vue dev tools 
})
```

The `form` is shared between every instance in each of the table rows, so the form.amount would be same for each. `bill`

when you call `payPerformanceFee` and pass it the `index`, it is unused by the method, so another way it is not behaving as you might want it to.

```js
function payPerformanceFee(index) {
    form.post(route('pending.bill'))
}
```

You may have better luck if you just use the `bills.value` with the index

And in the script move the form const definition into the `payPerformanceFee` method

```js
function payPerformanceFee(index) {
  const form = useForm({
    amount: bills.value[index].amount, //this show up as undefined in vue dev tools
    goal_id: bills.value[index].goal_id //this show up as undefined in vue dev tools  
  })
  form.post(route('pending.bill'))
}
```

In the table, because they are hidden anyway, no need to include the `<input>` elements.

Note that in this case, it expects the indexes to match (ie 6th row in table needs to match 6th object in `bills.value`) which may not be the case if the table can be sorted. If the index cannot be relied upon, you may need to use another id/key either from the data or define in component.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Daniel, following your suggestions solved my problem. I better understand how the template section works in relation to the script section from realising that my hidden input elements where unnecessary. This code gives me the inputs I need at the backend from each button click: ` function payPerformanceFee(index) {
    const form = useForm({
        amount: bills.value[index].amount,
        goal_id: bills.value[index].goal_id
    })
    form.post(route('pending.bill'))
}` Thanks!